# Branch points of a function $f(z)=g(z)h(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

Let us say we have a function, $f(z)=g(z)h(z)$ where we know that $h(z)$ is a single valued. Can we say that $z=z_0$ is a branch point of $f(z)$ iff it is also a branch point of $g(z)$? If this is true does it still hold if some of the functions are not analytic at that point?

Comment: You need at least _some_ hypothesis on $h$, since if $h(z) = 0$ you get $f(z) = 0$, which is most definitely mot branching. More generally, $h$ being zero along the branching points of $g$ would make $f$ nice and branchless (although it would still be multivalued)

Comment: do you mean that h is analytic in a nbd of z_0?

Comment: @Arthur You said '$f$ nice and branchless (although it would still be multivalued)' How can it be branchless and multivalued?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification Technically, $f$ still branching, but all the branches come together, so it's possible to choose one branch for $f$ and still have it be continuous everywhere (i.e. without a branching cut). I didn't formulate that clearly enough.